# Should I use State Managment on Authentication Pages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

I think about this question a lot. Do you think state management should be used on authentication pages? If yes, why?

I'm trying to use Bloc State Managment, but I don't know if it's right or not. Or how do I manage this situation in the most effective way?

Comment: Each status management has its own joke, whether it is more useful, simpler or more complicated to understand. If you are already using Bloc you should continue using it, it is very good for any situation you need, I don't recommend you to be installing several state management for different situations.